# Obtain an specific table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with SQL server 2008 and I built a table with this function:

```
    SELECT COD1 + COD2 + COD3 AS CODFINAL,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1  =  'BCO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'RIP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'MIN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'MAD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'CPR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PC1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'MAR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'LAC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CLu
FROM DBO.DATABASE
```

And I obtained something like this:

```
CODFINAL   A1   B1  B1    B1   PC1   B1   CLu 
B12030     1    1   1      1     1    2    3
C12130     1    1   1      1     1    2    3
D12230     1    1   1      1     1    2    3
E12230     1    1   1      1     1    2    3
```

But I would like to have a table with a unique total value like this:

```
CODFINAL   A1   B1  PC1  CLu    
B12030     1    5    1    3
C12130     1    5    1    3
D12230     1    5    1    3
E12230     1    5    1    3
```

Comment: So you want the rows to be concatenated into a single string?

Comment: Why do you have so many columns named `B1`? If you want to have multiple values in your case statement, you can rewrite it like `SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1 IN ('RIP','MIN','MAD','MAR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1`

Answer (score 1):

Could it be something like this?

```
WITH MyCodes
(
SELECT COD1 + COD2 + COD3 AS CODFINAL,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1  =  'BCO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'RIP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1a,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'MIN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1b,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'MAD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1c,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'CPR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PC1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'MAR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1d,
           SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1   = 'LAC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CLu
FROM DBO.DATABASE 
)
SELECT CODFINAL,A1,B1a+B1b+B1c+B1d AS B1, PC1,CLu FROM MyCodes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`in`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx):

```
SELECT COD1 + COD2 + COD3 AS CODFINAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1 = 'BCO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1 IN ('RIP', 'MIN', 'MAD', 'MAR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1 = 'CPR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PC1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SIG1 = 'LAC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CLu
FROM DBO.DATABASE
```